# IOS Pass object's reference to UINavigationController child

Tags: ios, properties, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In a `ViewController_1` I present modally a `UINavigationController`:

```
-(void)presentVC {
  UINavigationController *navVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someName"];
  navVC.HASearch = self.HASearch;
  [self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But I would like to pass the reference of `ViewController_1`'s object `HASearch` to the `UINvavigationController`'s child View Controller instead of `UINvavigationController` itself, in order to modify it in that child View Controller.

I'm trying different methods to pass it or to refer to that object in `ChildVC`, but unfortunately none of these work:

1. Instantiate the object in presentVC method by calling `navVC.childViewControllers`
2. Refer to the NavVC property in ChildVC: `self.navigationController.HASearch = ...`

Any other way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

The topViewController can be access via :

```
navVC.topViewController
```